# checkbox in YUI DataTable

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm using a column of checkboxes in a YUI DataTable, I works fine. But I haven't found a way to put a name and value attribute so I can use when the form is submitted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Could you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the API reference at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.CheckboxCellEditor.html help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a name and value attribute, you use a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="the_name" value="the_value" />
```

In your server-side code, you would look into the POST or GET data for the name of the checkbox. If it is there, the checkbox was checked. If it isn't there, the checkbox was not checked.

http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

How I reed a attribute for a checkbox, if I use YUI of Yahoo. Normaly I can use "document.getElementById(objeto).checked" but with YUI not work?.